# KML does not validate when an 'unsignedInt' field is zero

Tags: validation, schema, kml, zero

Consider this simple KML example that incorporates typed custom data via the `<ExtendedData>` and `<Schema>` elements:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Document>
    <name>KML does not validate when an 'unsignedInt' field is zero</name>
    <ExtendedData>
      <SchemaData schemaUrl="#DocumentSchemaId">
        <SimpleData name="UNSIGNED_INT">0</SimpleData>
      </SchemaData>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Schema id="DocumentSchemaId" name="doc">
      <SimpleField name="UNSIGNED_INT" type="xsd:unsignedInt">
        <displayName>Unsigned Int</displayName>
      </SimpleField>
    </Schema>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

In this case, only one `kml:SimpleData` field is defined. Its name is `UNSIGNED_INT` and its assigned type is `xsd:unsignedInt`.

***The trouble is that this document does not validate*** via this reputable [KML validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/). The error returned by the validator is:

```
"kml:SchemaData contains a kml:SimpleData value that does not
correspond to the declared type."
```

The reason the validator is indicating this error is because the field of interest has been assigned a value of `0`:

```
<SimpleData name="UNSIGNED_INT">0</SimpleData>
```

However, when the value is changed to a non-zero unsigned integer, the document *does* validate (as expected):

```
<SimpleData name="UNSIGNED_INT">42</SimpleData>
```

***My question is***, why does this validator flag `0` as not falling with the constraints of the `xsd:unsignedInt` type?

The treatment of `0` and `xsd:unsignedInt` by the KML validator conflicts with what the [XML schema standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#unsignedInt) has to say about `xsd:unsignedInt`:

> **unsignedInt** has a lexical representation consisting of a finite-length sequence of decimal digits (#x30-#x39). For example: **0**, 1267896754, 100000.

Finally, for reference, here is a list of all of the data types defined for use with `kml:SimpleField`:

- xsd:string
- xsd:int
- xsd:unsignedInt
- xsd:short
- xsd:unsignedShort
- xsd:float
- xsd:double
- xsd:boolean

(From the [KML validator documentation](http://service.kmlvalidator.com/ets/ogc-kml/2.2/#Schema-SimpleField) and the [OGC KML 2.2 standard, subclause 9.9.4.2.1](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=27810).)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with kmlvalidator, I would report it to them. I tested normal schema validation using Oxygen XML Editor and it validated.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that I report my findings to KML Validator support. I had already done so earlier today and included a reference to my question here in my report. Regarding XML validation...this won't do much good with regard to detecting KML schema problems. For example, my XML validator allows this: `<SimpleData name="UNSIGNED_INT">Hello, World!</SimpleData>`. That said, I'm not ruling out the possibility that there is a 'bug' in the KML validator. If that turns out to be the case, I'll report back here.

Comment: So, it's worth noting that Google Earth doesn't care about the data types either, it's designed specifically to allow interoperability and easy translation between KML and other data formats.